# Relação muitos para muitos entre várias tabelas

Tags: sql, modelo-relacional

Eu sei que entre duas tabelas numa relação de muitos para muitos 'precisamos' (não é obrigatório, mas facilita) de uma terceira tabela *pivot* que é o que relaciona convencionalmente os ids de uma com os ids de outra. Até aí tudo bem. Então e por exemplo para fazer uma árvore geneológica? Teriamos de criar uma tabela *pivot* por cada duas tabelas?  Em baixo está uma imagem para exemplificar uma relação entre pais/filhos em que existe uma tabela *pivot* (pais_filhos) no 'apoio':

Tabelas: `pais`, `filhos`, `pais_filhos` respetivamente. E por fim o `INNER JOIN` entre elas

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E agora se quisessemos adicionar uma tabela `avos` teriamos de criar outra *pivot* para relacionar os ids dos pais com os ids dos avós? E depois para adicionar bisavós também? Ou existe uma maneira 'mais fácil' de conseguir isto? Ou seja, sem 'precisar' de criar uma tabela pivot por cada duas tabelas? Eu sei que poderia nem utilizar uma tabela *pivot*, bastava arranjar um separador entre ids, por ex na tabela dos filhos criar uma coluna `id_pais` e aí inseria os ids no formato `1|2` e para os avós seria uma coluna `ids_avos` com `1|2|3|4`, e bisavos também faria o mesmo? Parece-me quase igualmente 'trabalhoso' se tivessemos tri, tetra, penta... avos.

Existe outra maneira que eu não mencionei aqui e desconheço para fazer isto? Qual a melhor maneira para fazer isto?

Answer (score 1):

Com **auto-relacionamento** você pode chegar a uma solução melhor e mais enxuta, desde que seja por "paternidade". Se você continuar nesse modelo e nessa solução, a cada nível, surgirá uma nova tabela.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS PESSOA;

CREATE TABLE PESSOA (
    CODIGO BIGINT NOT NULL,
    NOME VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    ANCESTRAL BIGINT DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (CODIGO),
    KEY ANCESTRAL (ANCESTRAL),
    CONSTRAINT FK_ANCESTRAL FOREIGN KEY (ANCESTRAL) REFERENCES PESSOA(CODIGO)
);

INSERT INTO PESSOA VALUES (1, 'SEU AVO', NULL);
INSERT INTO PESSOA VALUES (2, 'SEU PAI', 1);
INSERT INTO PESSOA VALUES (3, 'VOCE', 2);
```

Você poderia ter mais um atributo que seria grau (em relação ao ancestral). Trabalhando com consultas específicas você conseguirá bons resultados. Não sei se atende o que precisa.

Comment: Muito obagdo, mas acho que não estou a perceber. Se puder colocar um exemplo mais visual, como por ex, uma imagem das tabelas e exemplo de como se relacionam eu agradecia. não se esqueça que não é só a minha familia direta, são os meus primos, meus bisavós etc... Mesmo como se fosse ou arvore geneológica de várias familias

Answer (score 0):

Sim existe várias outras maneiras.

Uma delas: faz uma tabela pessoas com os nomes e dados das pessoas e uma tabela para os relacionamentos, em que tu tens o tipo do relacionamento, se pai ou filho e quem são as pessoas no relacionamento.
Por exemplo:

```
André (filho de) Francisco (pai de) Luiz
Francisco (avo de) Luiz
```

Então:

```
pessoas            relacionamento
-------            --------------
oid nome           oid id1 id2 tipo
1   André          1   1   2   filho
2   Francisco      2   1   3   pai
3   Luiz           3   2   3   avo
etc.               4   3   2   neto
                   etc.
```

Obviamente que coloquei aqui o tipo como `varchar` diretamente, mas pode/deve ser colocada em uma tabela separada para manter a forma normal e tudo o mais.

Comment: Creio que essa foi uma das maneiras que falei também, editei a imagem em cima, como pode ver é igual ao que fez, na realidade para o exemplo nem preciso do id do relacionamento nem do tipo.